# Is there a way to by-pass the pagination function on one custom template?

Tags: customization, templates, pagination

I'm working on a site where the client wants only the linked titles of all posts in a particular category on one page. That is, the query does not pick up the smaller number of posts that is defined in Settings from that one particular template.

I could do this if I by-pass the loop entirely, but is it possible within the normal loop?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to use the `pre_get_posts` filter, which changes the main query. That way you're not running the default query plus a custom one on top of it. You'll have to determine the "if" conditions to only run on the query you want to affect:

```
<?php
function wpse_366882_get_all_posts($query) {
    // This will run for all main queries that are not in wp-admin.
    // You may want "is_archive()", "is_page('slug')" or some other condition.
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    // Setting to -1 shows all.
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_366882_get_all_posts' );
?>
```

You can place this code in a custom plugin, or in a custom theme or child theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: So, as long as I have a unique name for the function and only call it on that one template, it will only affect the query for template?

Comment: You don't call the function on a template. The `add_action()` calls it at the `pre_get_posts` hook, which fires on every page, even in wp-admin. That's why you need the correct conditional to tell WP "Don't fire this on admin pages, and only fire on the main query" - that's the part you will need to fill in to be more specific and make it only affect the query you want to affect.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It seems that it would then affect all templates, not just one. I may need to just set up a new query object.that includes all the posts in that category.

Comment: You just need to set up the "if" condition correctly so it only applies to the template you want it to. If you run a custom query instead, you'll actually be running 2 separate queries on the page which takes up server resources for no output.

Comment: I see now that I understood "the query you want to affect" in a more general way than you meant.